# Kubernetes service is not reachable throw browser

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, k3s, k3sup

I've deployed a small K3S cluster with a master and two workers:

The VMs were made with `Multipass`:

```
$ multipass ls
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
master-node             Running           10.200.68.230    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
                                          10.42.0.0
                                          10.42.0.1
worker01                Running           10.200.68.67     Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
                                          10.42.1.0
                                          10.42.1.1
worker02                Running           10.200.68.227    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
                                          10.42.2.0
                                          10.42.2.1
```

The cluster was made with `k3sup`:

```
$ kubectl get node
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                       AGE     VERSION
master-node   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   13m     v1.21.3+k3s1
worker01      Ready    <none>                      10m     v1.21.3+k3s1
worker02      Ready    <none>                      9m46s   v1.21.3+k3s1
```

Workers are all labelled with `ols.role=worker`.

I'd like to install a `NodeRed` service on the workers nodes. I've used the following commands:

```
helm repo add k8s-at-home https://k8s-at-home.com/charts/
helm repo update
helm install node-red k8s-at-home/node-red --set nodeSelector."ols\.role"=worker
export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=node-red,app.kubernetes.io/instance=node-red" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
while [[ $(kubectl get node $POD_NAME -o 'jsonpath={..status.conditions[?(@.type=="Running")].status}') != "True" ]]; do echo "waiting for pod" && sleep 1; done
kubectl port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:1880&
```

The service is supposed to be running on port 8080.

Pod's logs look ok:

```
$ kubectl logs $POD_NAME

> node-red-docker@1.3.5 start /usr/src/node-red
> node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"

29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info]

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Node-RED version: v1.3.5
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Node.js  version: v10.24.1
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Linux 5.4.0-80-generic x64 LE
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Loading palette nodes
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Settings file  : /data/settings.js
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Context store  : 'default' [module=memory]
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] User directory : /data
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [warn] Projects disabled : editorTheme.projects.enabled=false
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Flows file     : /data/flows.json
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [warn]

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Your flow credentials file is encrypted using a system-generated key.

If the system-generated key is lost for any reason, your credentials
file will not be recoverable, you will have to delete it and re-enter
your credentials.

You should set your own key using the 'credentialSecret' option in
your settings file. Node-RED will then re-encrypt your credentials
file using your chosen key the next time you deploy a change.
---------------------------------------------------------------------

29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Starting flows
29 Jul 08:20:12 - [info] Started flows
```

When I try to reach the webpage (`http://192.168.1.14:8080` or even `http://127.0.0.1:1880/`), the server responds an error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

The services should be running:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    32m
node-red     ClusterIP   10.43.18.33   <none>        1880/TCP   26m
```

Is there something else to do to make it work ?

Comment: your helm is creating the service ? kubectl get service show the output

Comment: Here is the output: `node-red     ClusterIP   10.43.18.33   <none>        1880/TCP   26m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your service is Cluster Ip you can not access the service out of Kubernetes cluster.

You have to expose your service as **Node port** or **Loadbalancer**.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

however, for testing and debugging locally you can use this command :

```
kubectl port-forward svc/node-red -n <replace-namespace-name> 1880:1880
```

once command running open the browser and open URL

```
HTTP://localhost:1880
```

Comment: also command is only for local testing in prod you have to use the node port or loadbnalancer service.